# И еще о сумасшедших домах

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Во-первых, большое спасибо за ответ о "желтом доме", а во-вторых, задумался вообще о понятии сумасшедшего дома. Например, интересно, что его почти никогда так не называют, а в каждом городе за сумасшедшим домом закрепляется какое-то народное название - чаще по названию улицы, на которой он находится, или фамилии человека, в честь которого официально назван (Кащенко - в Москве, например). У нас в городе он находится на ул. Розы Люксембург (сейчас - Александра Невского), поэтому в народе психиатрическую лечебницу зовут не иначе, как "Розочка".
И второе - сама формулировка "сумасшедший дом". Почему не "дом сумасшедших"? Выходит, что сошел с ума сам дом.)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Вологде дом сумасшедших называют просто "кувшиново", по названию посёлка, где находится Вологодская областная психиатрическая больница.

Что касается самого названия, то "сумасшедший дом", довольно обычная для разговорного русского языка метонимия, например: *посёлок рабочих - рабочий посёлок, инспекция по труду, трудовая инспекция, зал для занятий спортом - спортивный зал* и т. п. Возникающая при этом двусмысленность для обыденной речи несущественна.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя сказать, что это название официальное. Обычно такое употребляют в разговорной речи. А официально - психиатрическая больница и т.д.